Applying the definition of (open)hereditary

The property ‘every non-empty open set is uncountable’ is not hereditary, but it is open-hereditary.

I am not clear on the definitions yet. 
Let me try applying the defn above. Let $X$ be a set with the property given in the title. Then $\{0\} \subseteq X$ and it fails to be uncountable, so the property in question is not hereditary.
Suppose the given property defines a topology $t$ on $X$. Then whatever the subspace of $X$ is $X$ is always $t$-open by defn. Is the proof of the given statement above supposed to be more technical than that? If so, how do I show it?

I can't really follow how your last paragraph would prove the statement. What you have to prove is: "if $(X, \tau)$ is a topological space such that every nonempty open set is uncountable, then for each $U \in \tau$, the space $(U, \tau|_U)$ also has the property that every open set is uncountable", where $\tau|_U$ means the subspace topology on $U$.

Before I move on to the second part, does the counterexample for non-heredity work?

@user1033615 Yes, but you should explicitly point out an open set of ${0}$ that is not uncountable.

Let us say that a topological space is beautiful if all its non-empty open subsets are uncountable.
Provided you are able to produce some non-empty beautiful topological space $(X,\tau)$ (a task which is easy but remains to accomplish), your counterexample (where $0$ denotes some element of $X$) shows that beauty is not hereditary, since $\{0\}$ is a nonempty open subset of the subspace $\{0\}$ of $X$, but is not uncountable.
In order to prove that it is however open-hereditary, what you must check is that if a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is beautiful, then so is the subspace $(U,\tau_U)$ for every $U\in\tau$. For this, simply note that since $\tau$ is closed under finite intersections, $\tau_U\subseteq\tau$.

Please consider the following image: https://ibb.co/7rYnkkn Would $\tau_U$ correspond to $A \cap G$ and $\tau$ to the collection of $G$s?

Yes, this is the definition of subspace $(U,\tau_U)$.

Perfect. Thanks.

Since $U \in \tau$, we have that $U$ is $\tau$-open. But $U = U \cap U$ with $U \in \tau$. Does that mean $U$ is also $\tau_U$-open?

Yes but that is off topic. Anyway, for any subset $A$ of $X$, $A\in\tau_A$. More generally, every topological space is open in itself.
